# Populate custom field via http request to account table in Dataverse

Tags: httprequest, powerapps, dataverse

I have added some customfields to the account table in Dataverse, when I want to populate them via the http request I use ( https://server-test.api.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/accounts ), I get a bad request 400 error.

I have published the table after making the changes.

Is there another step to take to get the api to accept my new fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use the logical name to use the new fields, the had a prefix added by Dataverse